# Read properties file from WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, properties-file, web-inf

I want to read properties file from WEB-INF folder and not from the classpath since I dont want to compile my application again if I make any modifications. My file is coming in build in the directory but when I am trying to acces its not showing anything. Please can anyone help me with this. I am using Spring framework. So if there is any method in Spring which will allow us that we are not required to compile our application again and again and the modifications are taken up by the applications on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application context configuration file and try.

```
<bean id="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>yourPropertiesFile.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

To access properties from the properties file, use the bean's ID in your class which must be annotated with `@Service` or `@Component`

```
    @Resource(name="applicationProperties")
    private Properties anyVariableName; 
    ...
    ...
    String propValue = anyVariableName.getProperty("propertyName");
```

Comment: Pam I am not using the annotations

Answer (score -1):

You can put the properties file in the resources folder. It will not require recompiling of the application.

In spring you can use the following lines to read the property values from property file :

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:dash_conf.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Also if you want to read the property file from java class you can use :

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: the OP is saying that don't want to use a property file from classpath